Strange PSEXEC Output
Windows 2016 server from 2012.
Sometimes when I run commands on multiple remote computers I'll get a strange output at the end of the command:
psexec64.exe \\<computer1>,<computer2>... CMD /c "<command prompt command>"

Strange Output
\\Ser????C:\Windows\system32\wdigest.dll:


When I've seen this happen, it's always at the end of processing the list of computers. I haven't seen this output if I send a command to a single machine. It's happened with at least one other command as well.
Does anyone know why it would say that?

Does it happen with other commands than shutdown ?

Can you please [edit] the question to show the command and it's output (formatted as code)?

@harrymc yes, I was also doing the command 'manage-bde -status' the other day, and noticed similar strange output.

Counter-question: Since this isn't Server 2003, this is Server 2016, and it has WinRM out of the box – what is the advantage of using psexec over winrs or Invoke-Command? (For that matter, shutdown.exe itself takes a computer name parameter, but I suppose other tools don't.)

@u1686_grawity I've never heard of winrs until just now when I looked it up.

I wonder why wdigest.dll is enabled - link. As to the strange message, my guess would be that this is a psexec thing.
